# Volcar datos de un reporte rdcl en vb.net

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer, dataset, informes

Buenos dias tengo un reporte en vb 2019 en un proyecto .net logro asignarle los datos carga correspondientemente pero al volcar los mismo a través de un for no logro poder asignárselos a una caja de texto de un informe abajo paso el código del evento donde se carga el reportviewer me dice que las cajas textbox son inaccesibles

```
Private Sub Cargarfamilia_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Aplicar_Filtro()
        Me.DataTableTableAdapter.Fill(Me.HOJADEFAMILIA.DataTable)
        Dim CONECTAR1 = New MySqlConnection
        CONECTAR1.ConnectionString = " datasource=192.168.0.xx;port=xxxx;username=xxxxx;password=xxxx;database=xxx3;Convert Zero Datetime=True"
        CONECTAR1.Open()
        Dim da = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT form1.*FROM form1;", CONECTAR1)
        Dim dt = New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)
        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet("Dataset1")
        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Local
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ds.Tables(0)))
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh()
        ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

    End Sub
```

los campos textbox del informe son apel ,parentesco , fecha lo tengo que hacer desde el informe ? por que no logro poder realizarlo desde

Comment: No te sigo, hablas de un for que no veo, de cajas de texto que tampoco veo...

Comment: perdon no lo puse por que no puedo llegar a llamarlos en el codigo me dicen que son inaccesibles